# How to set font family in a React Project

Tags: reactjs, webfonts

I have to use a specific font setting in my React project.

```
Fonts (Sizes should be automatically calculated)

H1 - Helvetica Bold
H2 - Helvetica Light
H3 - Helvetica Bold
H4 - Helvetica Bold
H5 - Helvetica Regular
H6 - Helvetica Regular
Body 1 - Open Sans Regular
Body 2 - Open Sans Regular
Subtitle 1 - Open Sans Regular
Subtitle 2 - Open Sans Regular
Button - Open Sans Regular
Caption - Open Sans Regular
Overline - Helvetica Regular
```

are the specs that I need to use.

I tried to use `WebFont` to do it. I put the code below to my `index.js`

import WebFont from 'webfontloader'

```
WebFont.load({
  google: {
        families: ['Helvetica:300,500,700','Material Icons']
    }
});
```

However, I am not sure how to specify other stuffs like Headers, Body, and Subtitle with it.

```
        <Typography use="headline1">headline1</Typography>
        <Typography use="headline2">headline2</Typography>
        <Typography use="headline3">headline3</Typography>
        <Typography use="headline4">headline4</Typography>
        <Typography use="headline5">headline5</Typography>
        <Typography use="headline6">headline6</Typography>
        <Typography use="subtitle1">subtitle1</Typography>
        <Typography use="subtitle2">subtitle2</Typography>
        <Typography use="body1">body1</Typography>
        <Typography use="body2">body2</Typography>
        <Typography use="caption">caption</Typography>
        <Typography use="button">button</Typography>
        <Typography use="overline">overline</Typography>
```

I try to render the fonts using Typography FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [styled componets](https://www.styled-components.com/) for this. Or even without this library create a component that will wrap children like `<Subtitle1>{props.children}</Subtitle1>` and apply font settings in local styles.